# Spatial join based on by location and by attribute

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-join, select-by-location

I have tried to solve my problem using previous similar issues but I didn't find anything.

I want to get direction for a shp (shapefile) with routes (polylines) and then to join this information in shp with points (for each route correspond two points and each route has a unique id same with the points that lay on this route).

I use the shp with routes in order to get direction (steps: first I split the routes in each segment and them I use the COGO tool in order to get the direction by ArcGIS Desktop).

How can I join the information from the direction to each points?

The problem is that while I have the unique id from each route when I split them then I have the same unique id in many segments so it makes difficult to join each point with a certain segment from the routes.

I cannot use direct the spatial join tool since it can join e.g. a segment with two points (when the points from two or more routes touch each other)

E.g. in the picture below you can see two routes (lines) and three points. the blue lines is associate with the two blue points and the yellow line with the point. I want to join the information from the blue routes to blue points.

[image]

Comment: Recommend you edit your question and add some images as it is confusing to what you are asking?

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pre-select the blue points and blue line then when you run the spatial join it will only operate on those. All geo-processing tools honour selections first. So I guess you need to work up some selection logic which you can implement through model builder or python scripting.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay in my response. After a couple of selection and some hand work I got the results.